# Passing an ID from foreach to modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass my `$model['id']` from a foreach to a modal which contains a form which heavily requires the `$model['id']` for if statements and functions.

I have tried putting a link around the button to use the usual `$_GET` however that forces the page to refresh and therefore closes the modal box, is there a way to prevent the modal from closing if the url contains an id?

Alternatively I have tried using the data-id passing through an AJAX post method and retrieving it in the modal. However the `$_POST` is not being defined, have I missed something or can it not `$_POST` to the same page? I am not good with AJAX so any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

There is way too much code in my page to post it all so here's a snippet of the important stuff

```
<button data-id="<?php echo $model['id']; ?>" data-modal-type="type3" class="modal_button customer_button right">New Customer</button>

<div class="modal" id="type3">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-title"><h3>New Customer</h3></div>
        <div class="modal-padding">
            <?php
            $customer_model_id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : 'ID not found';
            echo $customer_model_id; // Always shows ID not found
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
        $(".modal_button").click(function () {
        $(".modal").hide();
        var Type = $(this).data("modal-type");
        $("#" + Type).show();

        var id = $(this).data("id");
        alert($(this).data("id")); // Alert box shows the correct ID
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo doc_root('index.php');//post to the same page we are currently on ?>',
            data: "id=" + id,
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:
I think I'm getting closer with this JavaScript.

```
<script> 
    $(".modal_button").click(function(){ 
    $(".modal").hide(); 
    var Type = $(this).data("modal-type"); 

    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    $.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST', 
    url : 'customer_complete.php', 
    data : 'id='+ id, 
    cache: false, 
    success : function(data){ 
    $('.customer_complete').html(data); 
    } 
    }) 

    $("#"+Type).show(); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: @dakis 
Hi, I got it working now, But I have one other question, how would I do the same for another modal box? It just needs the url and $('.customer_complete').html(data); to be different..

Comment: Hello, Joanne. Good that it works. Did you see my answer too? About the new question: please give an exact description, not what you think is different from the first modal case (like url, jquery call, etc). So the same principle: you are the user, I am the developer. Please post the comments under my answer, not here. Then you don't need to prepend the comment with my username and it would be easier for me to refer myself to parts of my answer too, if needed. If you'd have 20 reps, I think, we'd discuss on the SO chat. But until then, we have to speak through comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write some code for you, because I found the task an interesting one. The code simulates the situation that you've presented in your question and comments, and is relatively easy to follow. You can run it as it is, but don't forget to replace my db credentials with yours, in `connection.php`. All files are on the same niveau in the file system hierarchy. So you can create a folder, bring all files in it, and run the `index.php` page. I used [prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) to insert into db, thus avoiding any [sql injections](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection) risc. I also commented that part, just in case you are not familiarize with it.

Have fun.

---

#### index.php

This is the main page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Modal</title>

        <!-- CSS assets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">
            body { padding: 20px; }
            .success { color: #32cd32; }
            .error { color: #ff0000; }
        </style>

        <!-- JS assets -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#type3').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                    var modal = $(this);
                    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
                    var modelId = button.data('model-id');

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: 'new_customer.php',
                        data: {
                            'modelId': modelId,
                            'modalId': 'type3'
                        },
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            modal
                                    .find('.modal-padding')
                                    .html(response);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            modal
                                    .find('.modal-messages')
                                    .removeClass('success')
                                    .addClass('error')
                                    .html('An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.');
                        }
                    });
                });

                $('#type3').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
                    var modal = $(this);

                    modal.find('.modal-padding').html('');

                    modal
                            .find('.modal-messages')
                            .removeClass('success error')
                            .html('');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button type="button" data-model-id="13" data-modal-type="type3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#type3" class="modal_button customer_button right">
            New Customer
        </button>

        <div class="modal" id="type3">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-title">
                    <h3>New Customer</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-messages"></div>
                <div class="modal-padding"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### new_customer.php

This page contains the form for adding a new customer into `customers` table.

```
<?php
$modelId = $_POST['modelId'] ?? NULL;
$modalId = $_POST['modalId'] ?? NULL;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#saveCustomerButton').on('click', function (event) {
            var form = $('#addCustomerForm');
            var button = $(this);
            var modalId = button.data('modal-id');
            var modal = $('#' + modalId);

            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: 'add_customer.php',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    modal
                            .find('.modal-messages')
                            .removeClass('error')
                            .addClass('success')
                            .html('Customer successfully added.');

                    $('#resetAddCustomerFormButton').click();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var message = errorThrown;

                    if (jqXHR.responseText !== null && jqXHR.responseText !== 'undefined' && jqXHR.responseText !== '') {
                        message = jqXHR.responseText;
                    }

                    modal
                            .find('.modal-messages')
                            .removeClass('success')
                            .addClass('error')
                            .html(message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #addCustomerForm {
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>

<form id="addCustomerForm" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="modelId" name="modelId" value="<?php echo $modelId; ?>" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customerName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName" placeholder="Customer name">
    </div>

    <button type="button" data-modal-id="<?php echo $modalId; ?>" id="saveCustomerButton" name="saveCustomerButton" value="saveCustomer">
        Save
    </button>

    <button type="reset" id="resetAddCustomerFormButton" name="resetAddCustomerFormButton">
        Reset
    </button>
</form>
```

#### add_customer.php

This page consists of code for handling the saving of the customer into the database.

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
require 'InvalidInputValue.php';

use App\InvalidInputValue;

try {
    $modelId = $_POST['modelId'] ?? NULL;
    $customerName = $_POST['customerName'] ?? NULL;

    // Validate the model id.
    if (empty($modelId)) {
        throw new InvalidInputValue('Please provide the model id.');
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    // Validate the customer name.
    if (empty($customerName)) {
        throw new InvalidInputValue('Please provide the customer name.');
    } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

    /*
     * Save the customer into db. On failure exceptions are thrown if and
     * only if you are setting the connection options correspondingly.
     * See "connection.php" for details.
     */
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO customers (
                model_id,
                name
            ) VALUES (
                ?, ?
            )';

    /*
     * Prepare the SQL statement for execution - ONLY ONCE.
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
     */
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);

    /*
     * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the
     * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first
     * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one
     * or more characters which specify the types for the
     * corresponding bind variables.
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
     */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'is', $modelId, $customerName);

    /*
     * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
     * When executed any parameter markers which exist will
     * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
     */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    /*
     * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
     * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them
     * so that the next query can be executed.
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
     */
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    /*
     * Close the previously opened database connection.
     * Not really needed because the PHP engine closes
     * the connection anyway when the PHP script is finished.
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php
     */
    mysqli_close($connection);
} catch (InvalidInputValue $exc) {
    /*
     * Throw an error to be catched by the "error" callback of the ajax request.
     * This can be achieved by sending a specific or a custom response header to the client.
     *
     *  - Specific header: A header containing any already assigned status code.
     *  - Custom header: A header containing any NOT already assigned status code. This type of
     *    headers have the reason phrase "Unassigned" in the official HTTP Status Code Registry.
     *
     * @link https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml HTTP Status Code Registry.
     */
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    // For all other system failures display a user-friendly message.
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    echo 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again, or contact us.';
    exit();
}
```

#### connection.php

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a mysqli connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling,
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 *
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

/*
 * Create a new db connection.
 *
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
 */
$connection = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
```

#### InvalidInputValue.php

This is a custom exception class. An exception of this type is thrown when posted user input values are invalid.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Exception;

/**
 * Custom exception. Thrown when posted user input values are invalid.
 */
class InvalidInputValue extends Exception {

}
```

#### Definition of "customers" table

I didn't create a `models` table, so there is no FK.

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data parameter is wrong.

try this:

```
    var idx = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo doc_root('index.php'); ?>',
        data: {id: idx}
    }).done(function( data ) {
       console.log( data );
    });
```

Comment: In your browser, please, open console - network, click your button and check if correct file called with ajax

Comment: There is a big chance that this doesn't work, since the ajax call is made from... `index.php`.

Comment: @dakis, perhaps you are right. But it would be informative if we could see the output of console to be sure.

Comment: It could be indeed useful.

Comment: Console log says the "HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)POST"

Comment: In your url parameter, try to replace PHP code with the static URL.

Comment: {"notifyType":"consoleItemLog","message":{"message":"","styles":"","hasFormatString":true,"fileUrl":"/test_modal.php","lineNumber":1180,"columnNumber":8}}

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you already have correct id value on the page. Looks like you get it from php script (*$model['id']*) and store in *data-id* of your button.
Also, looks like you're already able to get this id, when button is clicked. The further action depends on what exactly you are going to do.

```
$(".modal_button").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id"); //here you have an id
    $(some_selector).html(id); //to put it inside elements html
    $(another_selector).attr("placeholder", id); //to use it as placeholder (or any other attribute
});
```

This is for usage with js on the same page.

For POSTing it to the server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: your_url,
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        //some actions after POSTing
    }
});
```

On the server access it via $_POST["id"].

Why what you did was wrong?
Your POST request worked. You can check this using Chrome Dev Tools (Network tab). It posted to the same page and it's ok. The response of the server was an html page with id's built in modals, just as you wanted. But that was the response to the AJAX call and it had no influence to the page you already have loaded. Also, reloading the page you always had "ID not found" because reloading page doesn't make POST request.

Here is the general logic of what you need:
You already have id on the page. To transfer it to other elements on the same page, building into html markup and so on use JS. 
To transfer data to the server (for SQL for example)  use AJAX. You'd better create a separate file that would be an AJAX handler. That script will deal with POSTed id, make all required actions (like inserting new user to db) and send response (simple success-error code, string or JSON) back to the caller. Then, in AJAX.success you can handle the response and for example notify user if the operation was failed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That does help, thank you. I could use the separate page to do the sql and submit the form however how would I do my if statements without the id?

Comment: Where (server or client) when (on which stage: before anything is clicked/ after modal_button click? after modal submission) and which if-statements do you need to execute?

Comment: if($model['id'] == 15){ add extra fields } is one of the if statements. I can do the sql in the file I send the $_POST to but I can't do the if statements there...